# ionic capacitor qrscanner activity compat

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm creating an ionic capacitor application. In my app I have to use QR Scanner so I used https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner plugin to integrate qr scanner. Then I do `ionic capacitor copy android` and `ionic capacitor open android` . Then in android studio when I try to build it throws

capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/java/com/bitpay/cordova/qrscanner/QRScanner.java
   -cannot find symbol class ActivityCompat
   -cannot find symbol variable ActivityCompat

Ionic version is 6.4.0 and android studio version is 3.6.2

Can some one help me to solve this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Capacitor 2.0 uses Android X, that means all plugins have to use Android X too and that one is not updated.

As workarounds you can use Capacitor 1.5.2 or use jetifier to patch plugins to use Android X.

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetifier
npx cap sync android
```

Comment: Is this specific to some plugins because iBeacon plugin works fine

Comment: yes, it's only needed for plugins that use android support libraries, if the plugin uses any of this classes it needs to be updated to the corresponding class in the table https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Comment: in my case, jetifier is needed for QR scanner plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner since this plugin use Capacitor 2.0 and androidx

Comment: this approach works for capacitor 3 as well.

Comment: This approach works for Capacitor v4 too.