# ionic capacitor build cannot find symbol android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I start a new project in ionic. Only install the qrscenner plugin. After run command `ionic cap build android` run success. Then i run app in Android Studio, get error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
```

I installed floatinghotpot / cordova-plugin-android-support-v4 plugin, but same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115285/ionic-capacitor-qrscanner-activity-compat/61120845#61120845

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This can be fixed by running:

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

... which changed the import reference from:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

to:

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Reference:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capacitor-cant-build-due-to-androidx-conflicts-at-a-total-loss-on-how-to-fix/185535/16

Comment: It worked perfectly fine! Thanks much! I wonder how the guy in that reference came up with this solution.

Comment: I'm still new at ionic/android dev, but it looks like android.support.* is unsupported and androidx.* is the replacement. jetifier is a tool that upgrades the references of indidivual libraries.

Comment: This worked for me locally, but I am still having this issue when building via Ionic AppFlow. Any solutions?

Comment: i have not used Ionic AppFlow. But i did see this, may be helpful: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-support-v4-content-does-not-exist-appflow-build-issue/194978/8