# error: cannot find symbol import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

When I run **cordova build android** command, build fails. I am using **cordova-plugin-firebasex** for crashlytics from Google firebase in my Project. Below are my build logs:

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   39 actionable tasks: 39 executed
>   [01:36:56] 'cordova:compile' errored after 29 s
>   [01:36:56] Error: /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/cordova/plugins/Diagnostic_Notifications.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
>                                ^
>     symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.app
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/cordova/plugins/Diagnostic.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
>                                ^
>     symbol:   class ActivityCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.app
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/cordova/plugins/Diagnostic_External_Storage.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.os.EnvironmentCompat;
>                               ^
>     symbol:   class EnvironmentCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.os
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java:40: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
>                                    ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CordovaUri.java:25: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
>                                    ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/FileProvider.java:21: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
>   public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider {}
>                                                               ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintAdapter.java:31: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
>                                    ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintAdapter.java:32: error: package android.support.v4.print does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.print.PrintHelper;
>                                  ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintAdapter.java:56: error: package PrintHelper does not exist
>       private final @NonNull PrintHelper.OnPrintFinishCallback callback;
>                                         ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintAdapter.java:68: error: package PrintHelper does not exist
>                     @NonNull PrintHelper.OnPrintFinishCallback callback)
>                                         ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintProxy.java:30: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
>                                    ^
>   /Users/sbahuguna/DevProjects/mobile-apps/apps/netspend-gpr-android/build/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/printer/PrintProxy.java:31: error: package android.support.v4.print does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.print.PrintHelper;

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed this with following link.

[ionic capacitor build cannot find symbol android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195760/ionic-capacitor-build-cannot-find-symbol-android-support-v4-app-activitycompat)

Also I restarted android studio with on Android Studio->File->Invalidated Cached / Restart

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this in your config.xml file under android platform

```
<preference name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" default="27.+"/>
<framework src="com.android.support:supportv4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION"/>
```

Comment: There are some issues with this Cordova local notification plug in. I suggest you to use capacitor/core library which has inbuilt local notification. You can find a video on how to use capacitor local notification in youtube