# ionic Diagnostics Native Plugin not working on Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, diagnostics

I'm trying to build APK. After I installed Diagnostics I get these errors

> ```
> import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
>                              ^
>   symbol:   class ActivityCompa
>
> import android.support.v4.os.EnvironmentCompat;
>                             ^
>   symbol:   class EnvironmentCompat
>
> import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
>                              ^
>   symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
> ```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120845/1351469

Comment: woooow finally i got the answer! its working perfectly thanks @jcesarmobile

Answer (score 0):

as you are using Capacitor, you may have to use capacitor plugins as well instead of Cordova plugins.

Here is a list of capacitor plugins:

[Capacitor Plugins](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/community/plugins/)

Maybe these plugins are the ones you need:

[Permissions](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/permissions/)

[Geolocation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/geolocation/)

Comment: but i want to use Diagnostics and is not listed on the capacitor plugins

Comment: @NedlogApps there must be a capacitor plugin that does the same, but I'm telling you for sure, Cordova plugins won't work with the capacitor.

Comment: thanks again but i wanted to check the state of location change like if i turn off location then it fires