# Ionic capacitor-cordoca-android-plugins issue

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

So I've been working on an app for awhile now.

The issue is like 100+ error messages

Some of the errors

```
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/jakelewis/Desktop/tupperware-a/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Manager.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
                         ^
  symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
/Users/jakelewis/Desktop/tupperware-a/android/capacitor-cordova-android- 
plugins/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Manager.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
import static android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                                ^
symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
location: package android.support.v4.app
/Users/jakelewis/Desktop/tupperware-a/android/capacitor-cordova-android- 
plugins/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Manager.java:44: error: static 
import only from classes and interfaces
import static android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
^
/Users/jakelewis/Desktop/tupperware-a/android/capacitor-cordova-android- 
plugins/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Notification.java:33: error: 
cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Some debugging techniques I tried that usually fixes these issues when trying to compile an app on Android. Note that this app runs perfectly on `ionic serve` and xcode.

- Delete the android folder in the app project and create a new one.
- Invalidate caches / restart

Nothing I tried seems to fix this.

Works perfect on IOS and Windows.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120845/1351469

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I spent a lot of hours trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You may either migrate your project to AndroidX:

In Android studio: Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX, then fix your imports to make them consistent.

Or: Use jetifier to patch plugins to patch the project for AndroidX

References:

[ionic capacitor qrscanner activity compat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115285/ionic-capacitor-qrscanner-activity-compat/61120845#61120845)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate