# getting error on build in package name.ratson.cordova.admob;

Tags: android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins

I created new project using `ionic capacitor sync android` and was trying to sign apk key for the app

After running build I'm getting below error in `package name.ratson.cordova.admob;` inside capacitor-cordova-android-plugins.

Can someone please guide me on where am I going wrong?

```
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
D:\app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AbstractExecutor.java:3: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
                                 ^
D:\app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
D:\app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:8: error: package com.google.ads.mediation.admob does not exist
import com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter;
                                     ^
D:\app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:9: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
   .
   .
   .
   .
D:\app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:800: error: cannot find symbol
                        Uri tmpFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable FileProvider
  location: class CameraLauncher
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
86 errors

> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120845/1351469